# Chef execute resource error while runs successfully

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to unzip a file using Chef execute resource

```
execute "unzipping_webapp" do
  cwd "#{node[:config][:repo_dir]}"
  command <<-EOF
    unzip -o #{node[:config][:webapp_name]}
  EOF
end
```

Also tried

```
execute "unzipping webapp" do
    command "unzip -o #{node[:config][:webapp_name]}"
    cwd "#{node[:config][:repo_dir]}"
end
```

I am getting an error like

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[unzipping_webapp]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of        unzip -o webapp.zip
----
STDOUT: Archive:  webapp.zip
warning:  skipped "../" path component(s) in ../webapp/
creating: webapp/
warning:  skipped "../" path component(s) in ../webapp/bower.json
inflating: webapp/bower.json       
warning:  skipped "../" path component(s) in ../webapp/bower_components/
creating: webapp/bower_components/
warning:  skipped "../" path component(s) in ../webapp/bower_components/bootstrap/.bower.json
inflating: webapp/bower_components/bootstrap/.bower.json  
warning:  skipped "../" path component(s) in ../webapp/bower_components/bootstrap/bower.json
inflating: webapp/bower_components/bootstrap/bower.json
.
.More files
.
warning:  skipped "../" path component(s) in ../webapp/js/
creating: webapp/js/
warning:  skipped "../" path component(s) in ../webapp/js/app.js
extracting: webapp/js/app.js
STDERR: 
---- End output of      unzip -o webapp.zip
----
Ran         unzip -o webapp.zip
returned 1
```

When I am checking the system the file has been unzipped successfully.

I don't understand why my chef run is failing while things are executed correctly.

Has anyone faced this issue before or has a solution to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with Chef, it is that unzip is returning a non-zero exit code, probably because of a malformed entry in the zipfile. You can try the [poise-archive](https://github.com/poise/poise-archive) cookbook and see if that works any better.

Comment: When I am trying to unzip directly on the instance using the command line, it works fine. It is failing when I am running it with Chef

Comment: When you say "works fine" are you actually checking `$?` to make sure it is 0?

Comment: Yes you are right. It gives 1. Also poise-archive cookbook did the job. Thanks !

Comment: So there are two way in which I can resolve it. One use the third party cookbook for unzipping, second in chef's execute resource I can add **returns** attribute with 0,1 as values. 1 is used when it ran successful but with some warnings. Referred https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip for diagnosis of unzip outputs

Comment: Or you could fix your zip file to not generate warnings :)

Comment: Yes that is also true !